# Simulating right click on system tray icon and clicking on context menu in C++

Tags: c++, user-interface, automation, contextmenu, notification-area

I am a Python developer with a little knowledge of C++.

With that said, I would like to understand how I can right click on a system tray icon, and click on one of the options on the context menu.

I have looked around the internet and was unable to find something that can get me the location of the system tray icons relative to the 'Notification Area'. Also, I can get the Button text of the tray icon.

I get the handle of `ToolbarWindow32` using `FindWindowEx`.

I have tried to send `WM_RBUTTONDOWN` and `WM_RBUTTONUP` to the handle of `ToolbarWindow32` with the X and Y coordinates, using  `SendMessage` and nothing happens.

I am completely oblivious as to how I can right click the icon, and get the context menu information, and using that, click on one of the options.

Answer (score -1):

After my research there's no way to send a click message to a system tray icon, at least not through any API that I tried. The best way to do it and this is the way I'm following is the following:

1. You Send the message [TB_GETBUTTON](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787319%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to the toolbar.
2. This will retrieve you an "idCommand" for the button you retrieve so you can use a loop to get all the "idCommand", which is found in the [TBBUTTON](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760476%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure.
3. With the idComman you can send a message to the toolbar button with the toolbar handle to get the dimensions of the icon with the [TB_RECT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787346%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message.
4. Once you know the dimensions of the button you just need to get the dimensions of the toolbar which is simple because it's just a window you make a cal to [GetWindowRect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633519%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
5. Last step is now you want to send the click you make a call to [win32api.mouse_event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646260%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with x being: the left bound of the toolbar + half the width of the icon and y being: the top bound of the toolbar + half the height of the icon. (so you're sending the click to the center).

   That's it hope it helps!
   I've asked a similar question and answered it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21706428/click-system-tray-icon-python-win32).