# Winapi how to hide/show a third-party program window?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, windows-10

I'm trying to hide/show a third-party program (e.g. Discord):

```c
#include <windows.h>

void show_hide(HWND window)
{
    if (IsWindowVisible(window) == TRUE) {
        ShowWindow(window, SW_HIDE);
    } else {
        ShowWindow(window, SW_SHOW);
    }
}

BOOL CALLBACK enum_windows_cb(HWND window, const LPARAM lParam)
{
    const char* target = "Discord";

    char title[255];

    if (GetWindowText(window, title, sizeof(title))) {

        if (strcmpi(title, target) == 0) {
            show_hide(window);
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    return TRUE;    
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    EnumWindows(&enum_windows_cb, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

It's work fine, but if I hide a third-party program by click on close button, my program shows frozen window, until I press the tray icon.

Video demonstration:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P-_Fi-Dew1w

I also wrote message log through microsoft spy++ https://pastebin.com/YwGt88yh

It recorded three actions: click on close button hides program, click on tray icon shows program,  and my program tries to show window.

I also tried to add these functions one by one after ShowWindow:

```c
SetForegroundWindow(window);
SendMessage(window, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_RESTORE, 0);
UpdateWindow(window);
RedrawWindow(window, 0, nil, RDW_INVALIDATE or RDW_ALLCHILDREN or RDW_UPDATENOW or RDW_FRAME);
SendMessage(window, WM_ACTIVATEAPP, TRUE, GetWindowThreadProcessId(window, 0));
```

But it did not help. What did I do wrong?
I use windows 10.

Comment: I can't work out what exactly you are doing. We have some fragments of code, talk of close buttons, and some off site videos. A [mcve] would be ideal.

Comment: From that video, it looks like Discord is using a custom UI and window management. And its animated as well.  So, when the user "closes" the window to hide it, Discord knows to hide the window and disable it.  When you consequently re-show the window, Discord is likely not taking into account that the window was shown without user interaction, and so does not re-enable the window. Just goes to show why you shouldn't be messing around with someone else's window behind their back. What are you trying to accomplish in the first place?

Comment: Discord is just an example, the problem happens with any program. I'm trying to accomplish site wrapper (using [nativefier](https://github.com/jiahaog/nativefier)) and I need global hotkey to show/hide it.

Comment: Maybe you can [simulate click system tray icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21706428/click-system-tray-icon-python-win32), but I think it's going to be not easy.

Comment: @stade "*the problem happens with any program*" - I seriously doubt that. Most apps should be able to handle this kind of code just fine. Unless Microsoft has broken something severely at the API layer in Windows 10